# Display single item with Vue.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, vue.js

I have a  list of items where the title is a link to display a detailed view of the item. Click the title and it correctly goes to url + Id. In the Vue tolls the detail page retrieves the item with matching ID but as and array not an object and the template does not display any properties - what am I missing?

```
<script>
import axios from "axios";

export default {
  name: "Report",

  data() {
    return {
      report: {}
    };
  },

  mounted: function() {
    this.getReport();
  },

  methods: {
    getReport() {
      let uri = "http://localhost:5000/api/reports/" + this.$route.params.id;
      axios.get(uri).then(response => {
        this.report = response.data;
      });
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

The template is so

```
<template>
  <v-content>
    <h1>report detail page</h1>
    <p>content will go here</p>-
      <h3>{{ report.month }}</h3>
      <pre>{{ report._id }}</pre>
  </v-content>
</template>
```

any comments appreciated

[url + Id](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dd71B.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like your issue is that you are receiving an array not an object.

You can pull out objects encapsulated inside arrays easily.

For example, if we had the following data:

`var bus1 = {passengers:10, shift:1}
var busArr = [bus1]`

which we can assert: `busArr === [{passengers:10, shift:1}]`

We could then pull out bus1 by referencing the index 0:

`var bus1New = busArr[0]`

If you want to avoid the data transformation and just output the structure you can consider a v-for in your template.

`<p v-for="val in report">
_id: {{val._id}}
<br>
 month: {{val.month}}
</p>`

Comment: I just found another way - in methods add [0] to response.data to access the first object in the array. so it becomes response.data[0] an object is returned and the v-for is not required